# Angular 4 find JSON data

Tags: json, angular

I have this `JSON`: (this.url)

```
    {
    "user": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "name": "root",
            "password": "root"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "name": "clienttest",
            "password": "123456"
        }
    ]
}
```

and I have this service:

```
 findUsers(id: number) : boolean {
    return this.http.get(this.url)
    .map((res: Response) => res.json());
    .someOperator(to assert the id exist)...
  }
```

I want to return `true` if the user was found.
Is there some operator like `filter` that can make this assert for me?

Comment: Do you want to see if the results are empty?

Comment: yes, this can solve the problem

Comment: Assuming your service would return an empty array, you'd just run `result.length == 0` to see if it's empty.

Comment: if i do this:

 login(user: User) {

    this.userService.getUsers()
    .subscribe(
      users => this.usersArray = users,
      error => console.log("error" + error)
  );
for(let x of usersArray) {...}
}

knowing that the json content is on the usersArray I try to iterate but the console says: cannot read property lenght of undefined...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to use `Array.some()` method:

```
findUsers(id: number) : boolean {
  return this.http
             .get(this.url)
             .map((res: Response) => {
               let result = res.json();
               return result.user.some(user => parseInt(user.id) === id)
             })
}
```

**Inline simulation**:

```js
const data = {
  "user": [
    {
      "id": "1",
      "name": "root",
      "password": "root"
    },
    {
      "id": "2",
      "name": "clienttest",
      "password": "123456"
    }
  ]
}

// this will simulate http get resolve being processed by res.json()
const httpGet = Rx.Observable.of(data);

const findUsers = id => 
  httpGet.map(data => data.user.some(user => parseInt(user.id) === id))
;

findUsers(1).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
findUsers(3).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.5/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Property 'some' does not exist on type 'Observable<any>'.

Comment: you are right, I do not see it at https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/tree/master/src/operators. You can also try to use combination of find and isEmpty operators. Will update my answer

Comment: yeah, this should work but it's not. when i use .do(x => console.log(x) it's returning undefined. it only returns something with: .do(x => console.log(x[0].id)...

Comment: nice. it works but without the '.user'. just 'result.some'.
thx man

Comment: by the way, the return needs to be a observable<boolean>

Comment: the return of `findUsers()` function is an Observable which resolves to boolean. I think this is what was required